Move up in a treeview in tkinter
I have found this function shown below very useful to move down in a treeview, but I ask here if there is a move up function.
def moveDown(self):
    curSelection = self.tree.selection() # current row - from /68508694/
    nextSelection = self.tree.next(curSelection) # next row
    self.tree.selection_set(nextSelection) # set the next row to be the current row
    self.tree.see(nextSelection) # make sure the current row is shown - from /10155153/


Change this nextSelection = self.tree.next to this prevSelection = self.tree.prev and you should check for nulls, see comments:
def moveUp(self):
    curSelection = self.tree.selection()  # Get the current selection
    if not curSelection:  # If no row is selected, exit
        return
    
    prevSelection = self.tree.prev(curSelection)  # Get the previous row
    if prevSelection:  # Check if there's a previous row
        self.tree.selection_set(prevSelection)
        self.tree.see(prevSelection) 

